# Difference between last and lastlog?

Tags: last

```
last | grep IPADDRESS
```

doesn't shows any line, but:

```
lastlog | grep IPADDRESS
```

does. Why?

Comment: Does your version of `last` shows IPs? Or do you need to use `last -i`?

Answer (score 2):

Without more information it's hard to say, but they pull data from different sources. It's possible that's why.

`last` pulls from `/var/log/wtmp` which deals with more than just user logins. Virtually any change to the system-wide state is recorded there. For that reason it's an obvious candidate for `logrotate`

`lastlog` pulls from `/var/log/lastlog` which is only concerned with previous logins.

It's possible that `/var/log/wtmp` got rotated at some point after that user's login and that's why you're not seeing it.

To verify, you can run `last | grep "wtmp begins"` and if that date is after the login date given to you by `lastlog` then that's what happened and you would have to look in `/var/log` for the rotated copy of `wtmp` and specify it with `-f` for example `last -f /var/log/wtmp.1 | grep IPADDRESS`