# Why is there a difference between the last and lastlog command records, and why is there no recent login record for user in lastlog records?

Tags: tty, x-server, session, last

While testing the `last` command on my system I got the following result and could not make sense of the lines with *down* and *crash* at their ends, as all seem to be connected to a `tty7` login:

```
george   tty7         :0               Sat Dec 24 18:05 - down   (15:29)
reboot   system boot  4.4.0-57-generic Sat Dec 24 18:02 - 09:35  (15:32)
george   tty7         :0               Sat Dec 24 14:03 - crash  (03:58)
reboot   system boot  4.4.0-57-generic Sat Dec 24 13:48 - 09:35  (19:46)
george   tty7         :0               Sat Dec 24 12:48 - crash  (00:59)
reboot   system boot  4.4.0-57-generic Sat Dec 24 12:45 - 09:35  (20:50)
george   tty7         :0               Sat Dec 24 09:47 - crash  (02:57)
reboot   system boot  4.4.0-57-generic Sat Dec 24 09:44 - 09:35  (23:50)
george   tty7         :0               Sat Dec 24 09:41 - down   (00:01)
reboot   system boot  4.4.0-57-generic Sat Dec 24 09:38 - 09:42  (00:04)
george   tty7         :0               Sat Dec 24 08:42 - down   (00:51)
reboot   system boot  4.4.0-57-generic Sat Dec 24 08:36 - 09:33  (00:57)
george   tty7         :0               Fri Dec 23 21:36 - crash  (11:00)
reboot   system boot  4.4.0-57-generic Fri Dec 23 21:33 - 09:33  (11:59)
```

When I run `lastlog` also I get this result:

```
Username         Port     From             Latest
root                                       **Never logged in**
daemon                                     **Never logged in**
bin                                        **Never logged in**
sys                                        **Never logged in**
sync                                       **Never logged in**
games                                      **Never logged in**
man                                        **Never logged in**
lp                                         **Never logged in**
mail                                       **Never logged in**
news                                       **Never logged in**
uucp                                       **Never logged in**
proxy                                      **Never logged in**
www-data                                   **Never logged in**
backup                                     **Never logged in**
list                                       **Never logged in**
irc                                        **Never logged in**
gnats                                      **Never logged in**
nobody                                     **Never logged in**
syslog                                     **Never logged in**
messagebus                                 **Never logged in**
usbmux                                     **Never logged in**
dnsmasq                                    **Never logged in**
avahi-autoipd                              **Never logged in**
kernoops                                   **Never logged in**
rtkit                                      **Never logged in**
saned                                      **Never logged in**
whoopsie                                   **Never logged in**
speech-dispatcher                           **Never logged in**
avahi                                      **Never logged in**
lightdm                                    **Never logged in**
colord                                     **Never logged in**
hplip                                      **Never logged in**
pulse                                      **Never logged in**
george           tty1                      Sun Dec 11 08:41:03 +0100 2016
postfix                                    **Never logged in**
mysql                                      **Never logged in**
clamav                                     **Never logged in**
postgres                                   **Never logged in**
ftp                                        **Never logged in**
debian-spamd                               **Never logged in**
libvirt-qemu                               **Never logged in**
libvirt-dnsmasq                            **Never logged in**
systemd-timesync                           **Never logged in**
systemd-network                            **Never logged in**
systemd-resolve                            **Never logged in**
systemd-bus-proxy                           **Never logged in**
uuidd                                      **Never logged in**
_apt                                       **Never logged in**
mongodb                                    **Never logged in**
redis                                      **Never logged in**
mssql                                      **Never logged in**
sshd                                       **Never logged in**
```

Now I expected to see:

1. A login from `tty1` for *user george* (i.e. me) in the `last` command, rather I see `tty7` and with `crash` attached
2. A more recent entry for *user george* in the result of `lastlog` command, but I see:

   ```
     george           tty1          Sun Dec 11 08:41:03 +0100 2016
   ```

So I run `lastlog -u george` just to be sure I am not doing something wrong, and I still see *same date* as in `lastlog` command result.

```
Username         Port     From             Latest
george           tty1                      Sun Dec 11 08:41:03 +0100 2016
```

Questions:

1. Why are the entries for *user george* from `tty7` rather than from `tty1`?
2. What do the `down` and `crash` entry means as I have not experienced any crash as far as I know?
3. Why is there no *entry* for *user george* in the results of `lastlog -u george`?
4. Why is the *entry* for *user george* in `lastlog` from a *past date* when I have since been logging after that date?

**Note:**

I have seen this [Difference between last and lastlog?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/192078/difference-between-last-and-lastlog) and it does not answer my question.

Comment: Saying the provided link doesn't answer your question while it appears to answer it would certainly justify an explanation.  Both commands do not take the data from the same place.  I think your `tty7` is a terminal window opened in X, right?

Comment: As for the `crash` indicator, just take a look at the time the machine rebooted and you'll see the session in question ended abruptly because of the reboot.

Comment: The reason I said so is it doesn't address the reason why I have __an old date__ in `lastlog` records for _user george_ which is me the system owner. I expected to see a more recent date. Perhaps I am missing something

Comment: Ok I see, I often _reboot_ abruptly hence the crash. What of the _old date_ entry from the `11th` when I have since logged in many times.

Comment: Both commands rely on different information that is not controlled by them.  The `lastlog` strictly relies on actual logins, not session which are shown in `last`.  Opening a terminal window does not require you to log in.

Comment: So how come I can't see a recent entry for my _log ins_ in `lastlog`. Perhaps I don't understand what a _log in_ means to the system

Comment: I would suspect the last time you logged in to a shell (with a password prompt) was on the 11th.  It apparently doesn't log it there when you sign-on to your X session.