# Last users logged in the past 30 minutes

Tags: ubuntu, centos, last

I used this command in ubuntu to find the last ussers logged in the past 30 minutes:

```
last -s -30m --fullnames |head -n -1|awk '{print $1}' | sort -u
```

I need the equivalent for Centos 7.

For CentOS 7 I tried:

```
lastlog -b 0 -t 1 | awk '{print $1}'
```

But I don't know how to convert days to minutes. Is there any way to convert days to minutes in CentOS 7 with `lastlog` command?

Comment: I looked at the difference between the different versions and neither CentOS's `last` and `lastlog` have parameters that could suit your query.  You would therefore need to parse the output with some scripting based on the date.

Comment: Your `last -s ...` command seems to run fine on Centos7. `lastlog` is not an equivalent of `last`, see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/192078/difference-between-last-and-lastlog